# Calling Wcf .svc webservice in ios

Tags: xcode

i have .net service but i cant call it and bring data to xcode ios

the link is : http://"162.242.142.88"/CarShareService/CarShareService.svc/Login

can any one help me ?

pls remove brackets "" from the link

Comment: Please include your codes in the question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: i use alot of codes but all of them not working,did u make project before explain how to connect with xcode and .svc service?